# How to change SVG elements/coordinates of a bar graph in applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, chartist.js

I am using the Chartist library in AngularJS in order to create a dynamic chart in an application thatI am making. My goal is to change the css of the bars within the graph but I am not sure how.

When I inspect the HTML of the graph in the application, I see the following code:

```
< svg xmlns:ct="http://gionkunz.github.com/chartist-js/ct" width="100%" height="80" class="ct-chart-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 80;">
    <g class="ct-grids"></g>
    <g>
        <g class="ct-series ct-series-a">
            <line x1="22.5" x2="22.5" y1="45" y2="45" class="ct-bar" ct:value="0">
            </line>
        </g>
    </g>
    <g class="ct-labels"></g>
</svg>
```

I have found that in order to manipulate the bar graph that I need, I can change the x1/x2 and y1/y2 coordinates in the code above.

I have checked in my .html, .scss, and .ts pages but am not able to find any elements that look like they can be manipulated in order to make this change. Where would you go to manipulate these elements? Any help would be greatly appreciated.